# Integrating standard java into web frameworks such as Stripes, Grails JRuby and Rails

Tags: java, grails, jrubyonrails, stripes

For various reasons we have to use a java based web framework to create a proof of concept site. We've a lot of algorithms written in standard java that will have to hook into the site.

So right now I'm considering stripes, grails and jruby and rails. Bearing in mind I know almost nothing about any of these. My core issue is going to be, how easy is it to integrate our various java objects into the web framework.

I'd usually assume this is a straight forward process... but then again it is java and the web!

Anyone have any experience ?

Comment: I don't quite know your algorithms, they can be anything. So it's hard to tell. As far as I know, it's easy to write Java in Grails. But I don't know about other frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Groovy (Grails) can execute vanilla Java just fine
- Stripes is written in vanilla Java so no problem there
- jRuby can execute vanilla Java just fine

So basically, any of these frameworks should be able to handle your "algorithms" just fine assuming they aren't dependent on something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks - I'm assuming that it really should be something that is trivial, but of course assumptions can be incorrect!

Comment: Yea, questions like these are technical impossible to answer without a more intiment knowledge of what you're working with.  So the best that can be said is things will "probably" work. :)  The good news is that all these choices are Java at the core.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails it is pretty easy (I'm not sure about the other frameworks).

Grails encourages you to separate your "web" stuff and your "business objects" stuff - have a look at their "Service Layer" http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html.